# python VAR summary doesn't provide R2?

Tags: python, statsmodels

All, does anyone know whether there exists a function to pull out the adjusted R2 from each Vector Autoregression [via the `statsmodels.tsa.api` module]?  The standard summary output doesn't have the R2 info.

Do I have to calculate the adjusted R2 myself?  The coefficients are on stdout, not directly retrievable either.

Thanks much in advance!

```
                    model = stats.VAR(df)
                    model.select_order(15)
                    results = model.fit(maxlags=15, ic='aic')
                    results.summary()         

Summary of Regression Results   
==================================
Model:                         VAR
Method:                        OLS
Date:           Thu, 13, Oct, 2016
Time:                     15:37:25
--------------------------------------------------------------------
No. of Equations:         5.00000    BIC:                  0.0544958
Nobs:                     479.000    HQIC:                 -0.368344
Log likelihood:          -3164.54    FPE:                   0.526178
AIC:                    -0.642239    Det(Omega_mle):        0.446462
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: What module are you using? The only clues are names like `df`, `stats` and `fit`.  `VAR` means nothing in the general Python context.  It is useless as a `tag`.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. I'm using the VAR in statsmodels.tsa.api module.